# React Native - How to perform a really soft vibration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to perform a really soft vibration in react native?

I am trying to get the same vibration as in the app "Binance" (testing on iPhone 11) when pressing bottom tabs. I don't know if this app is implemented in React Native, but I enjoy the little vibration when moving between tabs.

But, when I do

```
   <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeStacks}
      listeners={() => ({
        tabPress: () => {
          Vibration.vibrate(); // from react-native
        },
      })}
    />
```

in my app, testing in the same device, the vibration is really hard.

I am not saying this for the duration, but for the very force of the vibration.

Any ideas? Is it possible using react native?

Pd: I have tried to use

```
Vibration.vibrate(50)
```

in order to reduce the duration, but it disappears (no vibration)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to use this [package](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/haptics/) from Expo:

And then add an haptic feedback like this:

```
   <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeStacks}
      listeners={() => ({
        tabPress: () => {
          Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
        },
      })}
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution for bare react-native projects(non-expo).
There is another library called :

[react-native-haptic-feedback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-haptic-feedback)

```
import ReactNativeHapticFeedback from "react-native-haptic-feedback";
const options = {
  enableVibrateFallback: true,
  ignoreAndroidSystemSettings: false
};
<Tab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeStacks}
  listeners={() => ({
    tabPress: () => {
      ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactLight",options)
    },
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 Vibration.vibrate([100, 1000, 100, 1000]);
```

Sleeps/No vibration for 100ms

Vibrates for 1000ms

Sleeps/No vibration for 100ms

Vibrates for 1000ms

don't forgot to import : import {Vibration} from 'react-native';